# How to delay re-render in Functional Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My goal is to delay re-render when the user gives an input, wait for about 2s before re-rendering.

The expected result is: delayed re-render down to 1 instance per 2 seconds. Instead of re-rendering for every state update.

The current resuls: it does delay the `text2` state update. It still re-renders whenever there is a state update of `text`.

```
function App() {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState();
  const [text2, setText2] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setText2(initial => initial + 1)
    }, 2000)
  }, [text])

  return (
    <>
      <form>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" name="name" />
        </label>
      </form>
      <div>{text}</div>
      <div>{text2}</div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Other idea is to use the `let` variable instead of the `useState` hook but suprisingly `useEffect` does not listen to changes of the `let` variable, so it does not re-render.

Comment: Consider using a debounce? Also, what's the purpose of this? (So we can help you with the actual problem you're solving)

Comment: Debounce or Throttle are good ideas for specific use cases, for example when you need a token refresh every X seconds or wait a few seconds after the user stops typing to save something. However, delaying the whole re-render process of React seems to be a bad idea, since it's the core functionality. If you think a delayed re-render would solve your problems because you have performance issues, then the re-render is not the problem but how you implemented your components.

Comment: When is `text` updated? Assuming text is updated on input change and contains the input value and `text2` is the characters count of the input value (wild guess, I know), you could handle everything in a `handleChange()` function.

Comment: @evolutionxbox phone authentication. I would like to automate the UI, so no `Next button`. The component run the `authorize()` method after 2s `to give chance for correction and unnecessary calling the API` when the PIN is filled with 4 number.